# node.js - Socket IO times out after some time

Tags: socket.io

I'm trying to build up a socket.io server for my own multiplayer game, but for some reason the server goes down after a certain amount of time and I don't know why. I have tried several ways to run the server (nodemon and forever, everything with or without screen). I don't think that this is an inactivity problem because I added a random stuff generator to simulate some activity on the server, yet the problem persists. My cpu load with the running server stays between 2-3 %. I'm running node 4.x and the current stable socket.io build (1.3.6).

And here is my code:

```js
var shortId = require('shortid'),
    io = require('socket.io')(process.env.PORT || 4567),
    mysql = require('mysql'),
    connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: 'localhost',
        user: 'xxx',
        password: 'xxx',
        database: 'xxx'
    });

var clients = [];
var clientLookup = {};

//Placed Components (builded stuff from players or enviroment)
var placed_components = 'Server1_PlacedC';


connection.connect(function (err) {
  if (err) {
    console.error('error connecting: ' + err.stack);
    return;
  }

});


setInterval(function () {
  var random = Math.random();
  //connection.query(
  //    'INSERT INTO '+placed_components+' SET ?',
  //    {data:countdown},
  //    function(err,result){
  //        if (err) throw err;
  //    }
  //);

  console.log(random);

}, 100);


io.on('connection', function (socket) {

  var currentClient;
  console.log('connected', socket.id);

  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////  
  socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    console.log('player disconnected', currentClient.id);
    socket.broadcast.emit('disconnected', currentClient)
    var index = clientLookup[currentClient.id];
    clients.splice(index, 1);
  })
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////    /

  socket.on('register', function (data) {
    currentClient = {
      id: shortId.generate(),
      health: 100,
      isDead: false
    };

    console.log('registering', currentClient.id);
    clients.push(currentClient);
    clientLookup[currentClient.id] = currentClient;

    socket.emit('registerSuccess', {id: currentClient.id});
    socket.broadcast.emit('spawn', {id: currentClient.id});
    console.log('connected players', clients.length);

    clients.forEach(function (client) {
      if (currentClient.id == client.id)
        return;

      socket.emit('spawn', {id: client.id});
      console.log('sending spawn to new player for playerid', client.id);
    })

  });

  socket.on('beep', function () { // Beep Request
    socket.emit('boop');
    console.log("received some beep!");
  });

  socket.on('move', function (data) {
    data.id = currentClient.id;
    socket.broadcast.emit('move', data);
    //console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

  });

  socket.on('ShareObject', function (data) {
    data.id = currentClient.id;
    socket.broadcast.emit('ReveiveObject', data);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
  });

  socket.on('SharePlayerAnimation', function (data) {
    data.id = currentClient.id;
    socket.broadcast.emit('BroadcastPlayerAnimation', data);
    console.log("a Player changed his animation" + JSON.stringify(data));
  });
  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  socket.on('benchmark', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


})


console.log('server started');
```

Comment: Does anything appear in the console when the server stops?

Comment: i dont know. my putty session just timed out to get the last informations on the console. it takes up to an hour, maybe more before the socket server timed out / crashes. maybe i can get a solution to create a crash dump log with nodemon or forever but i donw know how. greez

Comment: If you used forever, this means you have a log file somewhere because it created one by default.

Comment: well i found a way to create my own output and error log file for forever. i will run my server again for a few hours until it crashes again. i will post the log files when this happens.

Comment: i swaped from forever to pm2. here is the error log i get from one of the clusters before it shuts down all running clusters after 4 - 5 hours:   IPC channel with master closed
Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.
    at Protocol.end (/root/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:103:13)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/root/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:88:28)
    at emitNone (events.js:72:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:166:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:893:12)
    at doNTCallback2 (node.js:429:9)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:384:17)

Comment: seems that the mysql connection was the timeout problem. i switched the connection mode to pooling and now everything works fine for the last 15 hours. http://i.imgur.com/lV7dUB5.png using keymetrics to look up the node server.